# Angular EventEmitter on Observables

Tags: angular

Im trying to play with the EventEmitter for observablewith with Angular 7:

[Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular)

However the code they supply is throwing errors.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rk4l6k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fzippy%2Fzippy.component.ts)

Same code given by angular docs:

`<zippy (open)="onOpen($event)" (close)="onClose($event)"></zippy>`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'zippy',
  template: `
  <div class="zippy">
    <div (click)="toggle()">Toggle</div>
    <div [hidden]="!visible">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>`})

export class ZippyComponent {
  visible = true;
  @Output() open = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() close = new EventEmitter<any>();

  toggle() {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
    if (this.visible) {
      this.open.emit(null);
    } else {
      this.close.emit(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Error Thrown: `ERROR
Error: _co.onClose is not a function`

Comment: and what error is it throwing.

Comment: `onClose` and `onOpen` methods should be defined in `AppComponent`

Comment: @bryan60 Thanks! sorry forgot to paste the error

Comment: np, @yurzui is correct, you haven't implemented an onClose method (and possibly an onOpen method) in the component where you use the zippy component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to implement the `onOpen` and `onClose` methods in the `AppComponent`

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  onOpen($event) {
    console.log('onOpen', $event);
  }

  onClose($event) {
    console.log('onClose', $event);
  }
}
```